# Show that a group of order $2^7 5^7$ cannot be simple

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I wanted to know how to proceed for this general kind of problem.
I know that I should show that for a p-sylow $n_p=1$. But I don't really know how to study the other cases enough to prove it.

Comment: Another duplicate is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692529/no-simple-group-of-order-1-000-000?rq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188162/no-group-of-order-10-000-is-simple), perhaps better. The general case $p^aq^b$ is Burnside.

Comment: Sorry, now I found the perfect duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823562/how-to-prove-that-there-is-no-simple-group-of-order-10-000-000?noredirect=1&lq=1). Note that $2^75^7=10000000$.